# Как сделать интернет радио как pianorama.ru?

Tags: podcast, php, mp3

Хочу сделать так же как на http://pianorama.ru/, создать плейлист и чтобы он играл в интернете. Как сделать чтобы можно было такое сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если бы вы посмотрели исходный код страницы, то увидели бы что сделано во flash, и вот вам от туда же, если открыть http://pianorama.ru/uppod.swf, то ссылка ведет на http://uppod.ru/ - где собственно и идет решение вашего вопроса!